Schrodinger basis representation of modes in 2D CFT (Polchinski section 2.8)
I'm following the discussion on the state-operator corresponding in Polchinski Vol 1 Section 2.8 and am unable to reproduce the second terms in equations 2.8.25, which express the raising and lowering operators for the 2D massless scalar CFT in the Schrodinger basis. I have reproduced the first terms exactly so I don't think I'm totally off-base here, but I can't find my error. My reasoning is as follows:
First, we write the Schrodinger representation $\Psi[X_b] := \langle X_b | \Psi \rangle$ of a state $\Psi$ where the basis state $|X_b \rangle$ is defined by the eigenvalue relation \begin{equation*}
\hat{X}(e^{i \theta}, e^{- i \theta}) | X_b \rangle = X_b(\theta) | X_b \rangle.
\end{equation*}
Here $\hat{X}(z, \overline{z})$ is the Heisenberg picture operator and $X_b: S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ is thought of as either a classical off-shell state or a path integral boundary condition along the edge of the unit disc. Pochinski uses the mode expansion \begin{equation*}
X_b(\theta) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} X_n e^{i n \theta}, \ \ \ X_n^* = X_{-n}\tag{2.8.19}
\end{equation*}
so that we can equivalently write the wave function as $\Psi[X_b] = \Psi[ \{X_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}]$, so we make the analogous expansion of the Heisenberg field \begin{equation*}
\hat{X}(z, \overline{z}) = \hat{X}_0 + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} (\hat{X}_k z^k + \hat{X}_{-k} \overline{z}^k ).\tag{2.8.21b}
\end{equation*}
Here we have used the Hermiticity of $\hat{X}$ and the Heisenberg equations of motion $\partial \overline{\partial} \hat{X} = 0$. This notation is cooked up specifically so that we have \begin{equation*}
\hat{X}_k | X_b \rangle = X_k | X_b \rangle.
\end{equation*}
Great, that's our notation. Now we have the mode expansion (2.7.1) \begin{equation*}
\partial \hat{X}(z) = - i \left( \frac{\alpha'}{2} \right)^{1/2} \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{\alpha_m}{z^{m+1}}
\end{equation*}
plus the analogous expression for the antiholomorphic part. Meanwhile, our own mode expansion implies \begin{equation*}
\partial \hat{X} (z) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} k \hat{X}_{k} z^{k-1}
\end{equation*}
so by comparison between the two series we find (in Polchinski's notation) \begin{equation*}
\alpha_m = - \frac{in}{(2 \alpha')^{1/2}} X_{-n}.
\end{equation*}
But Polchinski equation 2.8.25 claims there is a second term here: \begin{equation*}
\alpha_n = - \frac{in}{(2 \alpha')^{1/2}} X_{-n} - i \left( \frac{\alpha'}{2} \right)^{1/2} \frac{\partial}{\partial X_n}, \qquad n\neq 0.\tag{2.8.25a}
\end{equation*}
Of course Polchinski must be correct: we should have a linear combination of $X_n$ and $\partial_{X_n}$, just as in the case of 1D wave mechanics $a,a^\dagger$ are linear combinations of $x$ and $p$. More quantitatively, my proposed expression for $\alpha_n$ and the corresponding one for $\tilde{\alpha}_n$ don't satisfy the Virasoro algebra. But I can't figure out where my reasoning is wrong.

$\psi(x)$ are represented by $a= (ix+p)/\sqrt{2}$ and $a^\dagger = (ix-p)/\sqrt{2}$. Here $p= i\partial_x$ when acting on wave functions. In the Schr"odinger picture we thus have
\begin{align}
 \alpha_n = &\, -\frac{in}{\sqrt{2 \alpha'} } X_{-n} - i \sqrt{\frac{\alpha'}{2}} \frac{\partial}{\partial X_n} \nonumber\\
\tilde{\alpha}_n = &\, -\frac{in}{\sqrt{2 \alpha'}} X_{n} - i \sqrt{\frac{\alpha'}{2}} \frac{\partial}{\partial X_{-n}} 
\end{align}
You get the same from Qmechanic's answer.

Thanks for taking a look. Kindly, I have already pointed this out in my original post: I understand why the expression I derived must be incorrect, and I understand why Polchinski's expression is reasonable / analogous to known expressions from wave mechanics / satisfies the Virasoro algebra. My question is specifically where my derivation went wrong.


Yes, the second term in eq. (2.8.25a) is needed in order for the commutation relations
$$\begin{align}[X_n,X_m]~=~&0, \cr [\frac{\partial}{\partial X_n},X_m]~=~&\delta^n_m, \cr [\frac{\partial}{\partial X_n},\frac{\partial}{\partial X_m}]~=~&0, \cr
n,m~\in~&\mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\},\end{align}$$
to be consistent with the commutation relations (2.7.5a) for $\alpha_n$ and $\widetilde{\alpha}_m$.

The inverse relations to eqs. (2.8.25a+b) are
$$\begin{align}X_n~=~&\sqrt{\frac{\alpha^{\prime}}{2}}\frac{\alpha_{-n}-\widetilde{\alpha}_{n}}{in}, \cr \frac{\partial}{\partial X_n}~=~&i\frac{\alpha_{n}+\widetilde{\alpha}_{-n}}{\sqrt{2\alpha^{\prime}}},\cr
n~\in~&\mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}.\end{align}$$



Thanks for taking a look! Yes, I noted this briefly at the end of my question \textit{More quantitatively, my proposed expression for $\alpha_n$ and the corresponding one for $\tilde{\alpha_n$ don't satisfy the Virasoro algebra.} so I'm quite confident that my answer must be wrong, and Polchinski's must be right. What I'm trying to figure out is where my derivation goes wrong and how to correct it.
